# How can I sub class CABasicAnimation in correct way for adding a custom property to the sub?

Tags: swift, cocoa, cabasicanimation

Here is my working codes for callBack of CABasicAnimation when the animation is Done. I am given the needed action to animation delegate, but what I want to be able do this work on sub class of CABasicAnimation:

```
extension NSView {
    
    func fadeAnimation(callBack: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let animation = CABasicAnimation()
        
        animation.delegate = CustomCAAnimationDelegate(callBack: callBack)
        animation.keyPath = "opacity"
        animation.duration = 2.0
        animation.fromValue = 1.0
        animation.toValue = 0.0
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .linear)
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animation.fillMode = .forwards
        
        self.layer?.add(animation, forKey: nil)

    }
}

class CustomCAAnimationDelegate: NSObject, CAAnimationDelegate {
    
    var callBack: () -> Void
    
     init(callBack: @escaping () -> Void) {
         self.callBack = callBack
    }
    
    internal func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        callBack()
    }
    
}
```

So the goal is having some code like this:

```
class CustomCABasicAnimation: CABasicAnimation {
    
    var callBack: () -> Void

}
```

which if that is done I would be able to code like this:

```
extension NSView {
    
    func fadeAnimation(callBack: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        let animation = CustomCABasicAnimation()
        
        animation.callBack = callBack
        
        // The other codes ...

    }
}
```

I have implemented my custom animation class as follows:

```
class CustomCABasicAnimation: CABasicAnimation {
    
    var callBack: () -> Void
    
    init(callBack: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.callBack = callBack
        super.init()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

When I run my code I get the error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

and:

> Fade_Test/ViewController.swift:57: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'Fade_Test.CustomCABasicAnimation' 2023-03-17 23:39:59.577008+0100 Fade Test[1810:79953] Fade_Test/ViewController.swift:57: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'Fade_Test.CustomCABasicAnimation'

Comment: @HangarRash: I tried your advice but I am getting new error of `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`, I show the code that make that error in up

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the exception?

Comment: On this line: `class CustomCABasicAnimation: CABasicAnimation {`

Comment: Fade_Test/ViewController.swift:57: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'Fade_Test.CustomCABasicAnimation'
2023-03-17 23:39:59.577008+0100 Fade Test[1810:79953] Fade_Test/ViewController.swift:57: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class 'Fade_Test.CustomCABasicAnimation'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that extending `CABasicAnimation` isn't as straightforward as it would seem.

You can't really add your own initializer. The documentation for [`CABasicAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation) states:

> You create an instance of CABasicAnimation using the inherited init(keyPath:) method, specifying the key path of the property to be animated in the render tree.

So really your `CustomCABasicAnimation` can only add the new property, but no initializer. This means your `callBack` property must be optional.

```
class CustomCABasicAnimation: CABasicAnimation {
    var callBack: (() -> Void)?
}
```

You can add/override other methods as needed to make use of the optional `callBack`.

Now your creation of the `CustomCABasicAnimation` will have to look more like this:

```
let animation = CustomCABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
animation.callBack = callBack
// other properties as needed
```

Comment: But it would this also work `let animation = CustomCABasicAnimation()`, I mean it is working for me.

Comment: If it works then I guess you can. The documentation indicates you should call it with a keyPath.